# The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -54.)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I get the above error when trying to run a project from Xcode on a simulator. When I click details it says:

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -54.)
Domain: NSOSStatusErrorDomain
Code: -54
User Info: {
    NSDebugDescription = installForLaunchServices;
    "_LSFunction" = "-[_LSInstaller installApplication:atURL:withOptions:installType:reply:]";
    "_LSLine" = 717;
}
```

*System Information : macOS Version 10.15.4 (Build 19E287)
Xcode 11.4 (16134)*

It was working last night. It worked once this morning. Then it stopped working when I try to run a simulator from not just one project but others as well. What is this error saying and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 8):

Restarting the simulator solved it in my case.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update my Xcode to 11.4.1. Not sure what happened that made this error occur in the first place when Xcode 11.4 was working fine for weeks, but that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me, **Device/Erase All Content and Settings** solved it.

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when no app has registered such a scheme.